# Select the "common functionality" iterator category

Tags: c++

There are quite a few situations when you deal with iterators of different types and want to know which operations are available on all of them. My hope is that you can deduce that from their iterator category.

Let's say, for instance, that you're writing a `chain_iterator`, or a `zip_iterator` and want to define its `iterator_category` from its components' `iterator_category`s. Is it a valid approach to say:

1. if at least one is an `output_iterator`, the common category is `output_iterator_tag`, unless at least one of them is an `input_iterator`, in which case the common category is undefined;
2. if at least one is an `intput_iterator`, the common category is `input_iterator_tag`, unless at least one of them is an `output_iterator`, in which case the common category is undefined;
3. else the common category is deduced to be the first of `forward_iterator_tag`, `bidirectional_iterator_tag`, `random_access_iterator_tag` to appear in the list of the underlying iterators' types.

To say it in code:

```
template <typename... Iterators>
using least_powerful_iterator =
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::input_iterator_tag,         category<Iterators>...> &&
                      !contains<std::output_iterator_tag,        category<Iterators>...>, std::input_iterator_tag,
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::input_iterator_tag,         category<Iterators>...> &&
                      contains<std::output_iterator_tag,         category<Iterators>...>, unknown_iterator_category,
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::output_iterator_tag,        category<Iterators>...> &&
                      !contains<std::input_iterator_tag,         category<Iterators>...>, std::output_iterator_tag,
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::output_iterator_tag,        category<Iterators>...> &&
                      contains<std::input_iterator_tag,          category<Iterators>...>, unknown_iterator_category,    
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::forward_iterator_tag,       category<Iterators>...>, std::forward_iterator_tag,
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, category<Iterators>...>, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
    std::conditional_t<contains<std::random_access_iterator_tag, category<Iterators>...>, std::random_access_iterator_tag,
    unknown_iterator_category>>>>>>>;
```

Comment: You're looking for something that works a bit like `std::common_type`, but for iterators, right?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes I do

Comment: As a bonus question, is there an elegant way to chain `std::conditional_t` ?

Answer (score 3):

`std::common_type` should work, no? The iterator traits have a derivation relationship:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    using map_iter = std::map<int, int>::iterator;
    using fl_iter = std::forward_list<double>::iterator;

    using cat = std::common_type_t<
        std::iterator_traits<map_iter>::iterator_category, 
        std::iterator_traits<fl_iter>::iterator_category>;

    std::cout << typeid(cat).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I've tested this but there seems to be no hierarchical link between an `output_iterator_tag` and a `random_access_iterator_tag`, although there isn't anything the former does the latter can't.

Comment: @papagaga You're right. RandomAccessIteraror is a BidirectionionalIteral is an Iterator. It is not an OutputIterator. 
Are you seeking to model categories or capabilities? The latter may overlap when the former do not.